# How to add metadata for other languages?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I've just added an application to iTunes Connect, which is mainly target the danish market. During adding of the application, I was told to enter the metadata information in english. After I added the application, I was trying to add meta in danish, but the language does not exist.

When a user in the danish App Store visit the App, the metadata must be in danish. Should I just change the metadata in english to danish instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add metadata in other languages for App Stores that have the English language as their official language (which is the case with the Danish App Store).

Do what most developers do.
Add the Danish text in the English description and if you want add below that the English version.

Comment: You're welcome. We do this all the time here in the Greek App Store :-) Unfortunately Apple didn't localize the AppStores after all this time...