# iOS Application Languages on AppStore

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have developed a game. Although my app is Turkish, the Language data on AppStore for my app is English. How can I change it? During the application submission process, I could not handle it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807159/how-to-add-metadata-for-other-languages

Answer (score 2):

Usually you can add any language by Manage Localizations, you can also paste Turkish text in English area for Description and Keywords, it just works fine.