# How to change or add localizable languages displayed at iTunes Preview of an iOS app?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store, localizable.strings

How to change or add localizable languages displayed at iTunes Preview of an iOS app? It is showing English but should be Português.

I understood that this change have to go within the app's metadata, using info.plist file. However the language Portuguese is not there for the key "Localization native development region".

I tried changing it manually and typing "Portuguese" as value, but now after app is Ready fo Sale, the language of the App at iTunes Preview is blank,

At iTunes Connect the app's Primary Language is already set to Portuguese(Brazil), but does not interfere.

Could someone direct me to the right way of doing it.

So I need to display at app's iTunes Preview, information that the app is made for another languages that are not English and to display more then one language when app is for more then one country.

I found a very similar question at [How to add metadata for other languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807159/how-to-add-metadata-for-other-languages).

Could anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem before. And I figured out that there was a third part library I used in my project that has multiple localization Language. When I remove that library the Languages in iTunes Preview disapeared.

So I think the way to change languages in iTunes Preview is to change localization of your app, not iTunes Connect Meta data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer jacky, I have sent new updates for my apps, with default value "en" for "Localization native development region" key at info.plist. The only place really handling languages should now be iTunes Connect. I must wait the updates to take place to see the results, I will post here later.

Comment: Two apps were updated and are now displaying the correct languages, the value for key "Localization native development region" at info.plist was kept default "en" for these two apps, it means that the only information taken in consideration were the languages set at iTunes Connect. However a third app that did not have update is still wrong. I don't really find a reason for that because all three apps are configured in the same way. Thanks anyway for your answer, that maybe right but I can not evaluate as the solution, I will make soon an update for the third app and hopefully that get fixed.